# Access automatically mounted owncloud/nextcloud mountpoint in gnome

Tags: bash, mount, gnome, owncloud, nextcloud

In PureOS (Gnome desktop) I have added an Owncloud instance (by using the Nextcloud configuration panel). Where do I access the folder I can reach by Nautilus via bash? In other words: Where is the mount point for Own-/Nextcloud instances?

I once found this by googling, however, now I do not with searches like

> where is Nextcloud automatically mounted gnome

get me e.g. to the [Nextcloud documentation](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/Nextcloud_User_Manual.pdf). However, there is no such information. More terminal specific searches usually give me results on how to mount Nextcloud by terminal which is not my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Found it by right clicking

[image: here]

So the folder location is

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/dav:host=<host>,ssl=true,user=<user>,prefix=%2Fowncloud%2Fremote.php%2Fwebdav
```